# How to pull all the product id, skus, product names, description, images,category in magento using only mysql?

Tags: mysql, magento

How to pull all the `product id, skus, product names, description, images, category` in Magneto using only MySQL?

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Select all products and category in magento and insert wordpress project.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.`entity_id`, p.`sku`, pv.`value` as name, pt.`value` as description, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cp.`category_id`) SEPARATOR ', ') as categories, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pm.`value`) SEPARATOR ', ') as imagesPath
FROM `catalog_product_entity` as p
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as pv on pv.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and     pv.`attribute_id` = 71
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` as pt on pt.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and pt.`attribute_id` = 72
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product` as cp on cp.`product_id` = p.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` as pm on pm.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and pm.`attribute_id` = 88
GROUP BY cp.`product_id`, pm.`entity_id`
```

The query is designed for EE v1.13.1.0 it should fit for other versions, but recheck your attributeIds in `eav_attribute` table

Answer (score 0):

**This query return Product name, sku, price, image, description based on admin storeID & two other also..**

SET @etype = (SELECT 
                    entity_type_id
                FROM
                    eav_entity_type
                WHERE
                    entity_type_code = 'catalog_product');
-- Product name attribute ID
SET @name  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'name'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
-- Product image attribute ID
SET @image  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'image'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);

-- Product price attribute ID

SET @price  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'price'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);

-- Product description attribute ID

SET @description  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'description'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);

-- Query
SELECT 
    e.entity_id AS 'id',
    e.sku,
    v1.value AS 'name',
    v2.value AS 'image',
    si.qty AS 'stock qty',
    d1.value AS 'price',
    s1.value AS 'description'
FROM
    catalog_product_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    cataloginventory_stock_item si ON e.entity_id = si.product_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v1 ON e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
        AND v1.store_id IN (0,1,2)
        AND v1.attribute_id = @name
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.entity_id
        AND v2.store_id IN (0,1,2)
        AND v2.attribute_id = @image 
        LEFT JOIN
    LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal d1 ON e.entity_id = d1.entity_id
        AND d1.store_id IN (0,1,2)
        AND d1.attribute_id = @price
        LEFT JOIN
        catalog_product_entity_text s1 ON e.entity_id = s1.entity_id
       AND s1.store_id IN (0,1,2)
       AND s1.attribute_id = @description ;